# Prove that if 2 divides $x^2-5$ then 4 divides $x^2-5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, fake-proofs

so I have to prove this and I use two different types of proof and I came to a contradicting result. Can someone point out an error I made?

Using a direct proof:
If 2 divides $x^2-5$ than $x^2-5=2k$ from that $x^2=2(k+2)+1$. From that we know x is odd. since x is odd x=2y+1. From that $(2y+1)^2-5=4y^2+4y-4=4(y^2+y+1)$ so the implication is true.

Using a contrapositive proof.
If 4 does not divide $x^2-5$ then we have 3 cases.\
$x^2-5=4k+1$\
$x^2-5=4k+2$\
$x^2-5=4k+3$\

Looking at the second case we have $4k+2=2(2k+1)$. Therefore the implication is false as from truth we have false. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You *want* the result to be wrong.  That means your assumption was wrong.  Now just show their is a problem with the other two.

Comment: I don't really understand. If the contrapositive is ture then the implication is true.

Comment: If your implication is true, your contrapositive is true. So to go "the other way" you could take a look at the converse

Comment: No.  If the contrapositive is true then you can't conclude anything.  It's always possible to get a true result from a false premise.  You just can't get to false result from a true premise.

Comment: Implication and the contrapositive is logically equivalent. Hence if one is true than the other is true. So, if contrapositive is false so is the implication.

Comment: Assuming that tiger isn't a cat doesn't rule out that it's not a mammal.  You have to take the case it's divisible by 2 but not 4 and show that *that* isn't a contradiction.  That you didn't get the contradiction right out the door doesn't mean you did any thing wrong.  It just means you need to do more work.

Comment: You are talking about the direct proof. Yes i did not get any contradiction. But when i get a different result form the contrapositive then i got a different result. That should not happen as they are logically equivalent.

Comment: You haven't finished.  You must keep going.  Getting a temporary agreement doesn't mean the argreement will last.  Yes, that assumption says it is even is in agreement with what you are trying to prove false.  It's disappointing but it's still possible to prove this is assumption is still impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $x^2-5$ is not divisible by $2$ when it is of the form $4k-1$ or $4k-3$. So suppose $x^2-5 = 4k-2$. This quantity is certainly divisible by $2$ if there is such an integer $k$, which is why we need to do a bit more analysis to make sure something fishy isn't going on. From this we have $$x^2 = 4k+3$$ which makes $x$ odd, so let $ x= 2y+1$ to get $$\begin{align}(2y+1)^2 = 4k+3 \\ \implies 4y^2+4y+1 = 4k+3 \\ \implies 4y^2+4y = 4k+2 \\ \implies 2(y^2+y) = 2k+1\end{align}$$ Now the LHS is necessarily even while the RHS is necessarily odd, a contradiction. Hence no such integer $y$ exists, meaning no such integer $x$ exists such that $x^2-5$ can take the form $4k+2$ for any integer $k$. This is enough to complete the proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Oh wow it is all clear now. Although it was a possible case it was not a one after all, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Sorfosh Yes, the contradiction was assuming that $x^2-5$ could ever equal $4k\pm 2$. Happy to help!